# toLowerCase not working

Tags: apex

I'm attempting to convert the strings in a list to lower case with the following loop and it's not working. The capitals remain.

```
for(String s : DegreeOfferingValues){
            s.toLowerCase();
            System.debug(s);
        }
```

The debug logs shows:

```
[220]|DEBUG|DegreeOfferingValues (den-mba, den-msw, No Degree Offering Set)
[226]|DEBUG|den-mba
[226]|DEBUG|den-msw
[226]|DEBUG|No Degree Offering Set
```

Am I missing something completely obvious here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to overwrite the value of s with the lower case conversion. In the example below, the first debug is showing you the value you are iterating with (each element of the List). The second debug is showing you what happens when you call the toLowerCase() method.

```
List<String> DegreeOfferingValues = new List<String>{'apple', 'orange', 'PEAR'};
    for(String s : DegreeOfferingValues){
        s.toLowerCase();
        System.debug(s);
        System.debug('>>>' + s.toLowerCase());
    }
```

Change needed to convert List values and store in same position:

```
List<String> DegreeOfferingValues = new List<String>{'apple', 'orange', 'PEAR'};
for(Integer i=0; i<DegreeOfferingValues.size(); i++){
    DegreeOfferingValues[i] = DegreeOfferingValues[i].toLowerCase();
}

System.debug('>>>' + DegreeOfferingValues);
```

You could also create a new list if you needed to keep reference to old values.

Comment: Thanks, the key here was remembering the method only returns values doesn't assign them.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not updating the value of s. The function will make it to lower case but will not assign a new value to the variable. Try,

```
for(String s : DegreeOfferingValues){
            s.toLowerCase();
            System.debug(s.toLowerCase());
        }
```

To store the value,

```
for(String s : DegreeOfferingValues){
                String s1 = s.toLowerCase();
                System.debug(s1);
            }
```